Large Multipart.File uploads directly to AWS S3
I have a go-chi (golang) web application that is hosted behind nginx (reverse proxy -   proxy_pass directives), that accepts file uploads that are then uploaded to AWS S3.
The request with a file is sent via a POST request with a content-type of multipart/form-data.
The application then receives the request and creates a multipart.file type, this entire file from my understanding is allocated in memory.
I would like to accept files that can be in the range of 5gb - 10gb, and cannot increase server memory of this size, as I only have 2gb.
S3 has multipart upload methods, which will allow to uploading of parts of the file to S3.
I have implemented this multipart file upload in go below, The issue I am facing is I feel there is duplicated effort since go-http library is already allocating memory in parts to make the *multipart.file type essentially doing what I am doing below.

Is there a way to take these part files created by the go-http library in the ParseMultipartForm() and upload to S3 directly to avoid the the allocation of the entire file in memory? (uploading the file stream as it comes in)

Would it be better to just avoid the parsing and allocating of the mutlipart.file in go-http and load it directly to disk, then use the multipart s3 methods to upload the file parts? Although I believe I would still need to stream the entire file in memory to do so, which will not work as I do not have enough memory

Is Nginx parsing and parting this file as well, before passing it to the webapp?


I have implemented a light POC of S3 multipart uploads below.
partBufSize := int64(10000000)
byteOffset := int64(0)

for { 
    remainingStreamBytes := uploadSize - bytesOffset
    if remainingStreamBytes < partBufSize {
        partBufSize = remainingStreamBytes
    }

    _, _ = uploadedFile.Seek(bytesOffset, io.SeekStart)

    filePartBuffer := make([]byte, partBufSize)
    _, err := uploadedFile.Read(filePartBuffer)
    if err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        log.Error().Msg(err.Error())
    }

    uploadPartRes, err := s3Client.UpParts(&aws.PartObjectInput{
        Key:      uploadPartsRequest.Key,
        Body:     bytes.NewReader(filePartBuffer),
        PartNum:  aws.Int64(int64(count)),
        UpId:     uploadPartsRequest.UploadId,
        PartSize: aws.Int64(partBufSize),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Msg(err.Error())
    }
    bytesOffset = bytesOffset + partBufSize

    compParts = append(compParts, &s3.CompletedPart{
        ETag:       uploadPartRes.ETag,
        PartNumber: aws.Int64(int64(count)),
    })
    count++
}


There's an official AWS SDK which handles S3 for you.

Ah thanks, this would have saved me some time and code. @Schwern

FWIW:  Unless you have a compelling reason to avoid it, you can avoid all of the memory issues by providing presigned URLs to the web client and have the web client upload the object to S3 directly.

@AnonCoward I do, its a public application, and I rather not expose information in regards to where files are uploaded and where infrastructure is hosted.

"and creates a multipart.file type, this entire file from my understanding is allocated in memory." Which part of tho documentation https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm hints at this behaviour?

@Volker I see you specify the allotted memory - then the rest to disk, I missed the last part of "remainder stored on disk in temp files" and believed that setting this allocation would be the part size, for the file in buffers.


The application then receives the request and creates a multipart.file type, this entire file from my understanding is allocated in memory.

I do not quite get this. If this is the way you've coded that, then just don't do that: Go provides mime/multipart.Reader which can be used to read multipart/form-data-encoded payloads piecemeal.
To do that, you roll like this:

Get the value of the Content-Type header field and parse it with the mime.ParseMediaType function to get the value of its "boundary" parameter—a string used to separate parts in the multipart payload.
Create a multipart.Reader out of the request's body and the boundary string.
Iterate over the parts; at each part, you'll get another io.Reader which will provide the part's bytes. Do whatever you want with those bytes—possibly shoveling them into an active POST request using io.Copy or io.CopyN.

This way you will control the exact amount of buffering you want to provide.

I see that multipartReader in go-chi offers this as an option over the ParseMultipartForm method which as the commenter pointed out stores a specified amount in memory, and the rest on disk for later processing. Thanks for pointing out mulitpart.Reader.
